# CSS height 100% two columns

Tags: html, css

I have a two columns layout, two of them have a 100% height. So far so good.

The issue rises when the left column (example below) content expands as a result of 
a drop down menu.

Take a look at the markup below. I intentionally set another div inside the left one
to illustrate the right box is not expanding according to the left one.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html style="min-height:100%;height:100%">
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
        <body style="min-height:100%;margin:0;background-color:#ccc;height:100%">

        <div style="width:30%;background-color:green;;float:left;min-height:100%"><div style="height:900px">Green</div></div>
        <div style="width:60%;background-color:red;float:right;min-height:100%">Red</div>

        </body>
</html>
```

What will be a good solution to get the right box to expand in height; whenever 
the left one does?

Comment: read [this](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).

Answer (score 1):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bx8Mx/)**

**css**

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
.container{
    display:table;
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.green{
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:green;
    width:50%;
}
.red{
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="red">red</div>
</div>
```

---

OR

`Help Full` `Links` for you.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm

Comment: That seems to work, but I'm sure using a table-cell will come bite me in ars at some point. Is there another way around this ?

Comment: [`table-cell` is supported by all current browsers and IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Comment: @elad.chen another way to use jquerry i think height 100%; set from jqueery

Comment: Scratch that, it doesn't work. Both the green and red boxes now have the height of an inline element..

Comment: Solved it on my own.. This can be achieved by setting the entire body background color to the color of the right column, thus creating an illusion its always there.. :)